# How to add noVNC in dockerised jupyterlab

Tags: python-3.x, docker, jupyter-lab, novnc

I have created below the dockerfile and added [novnc](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC) and [websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify) as per their documentation. After the docker run, I could see the connect page on the browser after copy-and-paste URL that is output by the `novnc_proxy` script inside the docker entry point.

However as soon as I tried to click connect it gives me an error message `failed to connect the server`. Does anyone know, how to fix this error?  or Is there some configuration I'm missing out on to run the VNC?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8.0

ENV DISPLAY :1

RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it.git ~/.bash_it && \
    bash ~/.bash_it/install.sh --silent


RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs \
                       supervisor \
                       openssl \
                       xvfb \
                       x11vnc \
                       openbox && apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade \
    PyVirtualDisplay \
    pillow \
    numpy \
    pandas \
    dash \
    Jupyterlab \
    ipywidgets \
    jupyterlab-git \
    jupyter-server-proxy \
    jupyter-dash \
    jupyterlab-novnc \
    nbserverproxy

RUN jupyter lab build
# RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
#     pip install --upgrade \
#     jupyterlab "pywidgets>=7.5"
RUN jupyter serverextension enable --py nbserverproxy

RUN jupyter labextension install \
    jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3 \
    @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager \
    @jupyterlab/git \
    @jupyterlab/server-proxy

COPY config/ /root/.jupyter/


VOLUME /notebooks
WORKDIR /notebooks

RUN git clone https://github.com/novnc/noVNC.git ./novnc  && \
    git clone https://github.com/novnc/websockify.git ./novnc/utils/websockify

COPY entrypoint.sh .

RUN chmod -R 755 /notebooks/
EXPOSE 8888 8050 5901 6080 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["/notebooks/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
echo
jupyter lab --allow-root --ip=* --port=8888 &
/notebooks/novnc/utils/novnc_proxy --vnc localhost:5901 --listen 6080
fg %1
```

I build the docker image and run the docker image
`docker run -it  -p 8888:8888 -p 8050:8050 -p 5901:5901 -p 6080:6080 <ImageName>`

O/p of this docker run looks like this:

[image: noVNCoutput]

and instead of the url showing in std output, if I try to login `http://localhost:6080/vnc.html?host=localhost&port=6080`  it shows me the login browser of [image: noVNC browser] but as soon as I click on connect it shows `failed to connect the server`

and docker log shows me
[image: connection Refused]

Inside the container, I could see `websockify` service is running

[image: Inside container]

I suspect it's because of websocket connection issue, but don't know what needs to be done here.

[image: Websocket]

Comment: Issue fixed: I'm not sure if this is the issue inside the container I was running x11vnc but as soon as I change it to just vncserver .... everything just started running fine.

Comment: change198 can you publish the Dockerfile that worked please... or the github location if you have one. Regards.